# rrt_exploration : tree starting point

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,
i'm currently testing this [package](https://github.com/hasauino/rrt_exploration) (rtt_exploration) in Gazebo, in order to include it in a future project, and I have a question concerning this paragraph :

> clicked_point (geometry_msgs/PointStamped Message): The global_rrt_frontier_detector node requires that the region to be explored is defined. This topic is where the node recieves five points that define the region. The first four points are four defining a square region to be explored, and ***the last point is the tree starting point***. After publishing those five points on this topic, the RRT will start detecting frontier points. The five points are intended to be published from Rviz using alt text button.

I didn't understand what the last point's purpose,
and how can I place it efficiently ?

thank you for your help !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276630/rrt_exploration-:-tree-starting-point/) by [StanSmooth](https://answers.ros.org/users/32748/stansmooth/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2017-11-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After you publish the four points which define a square region (to be explored), the fifth point defines where the tree shall start (initiation point for the detectors). This [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/rrt_exploration/Tutorials/singleRobot) has a GIF image showing the sequence for publishing those five points.

The initial point for the detectors is not that important. It could be anywhere in the known area (white space in the occupancy grid) of the defined region.

---

Originally posted by [hasauino](https://answers.ros.org/users/26499/hasauino/) with karma: 91 on 2017-11-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [StanSmooth](https://answers.ros.org/users/32748/stansmooth/) on 2017-11-28**:
Thank you !